# How do I get csv file from excel into R environment with the file.choose function?

Tags: r, csv, xlsx, filechooser

I am new to the progamming world so I am following a Udemy course on R and I am to enter a command like this: mydata <- read.csv(file.choose())

which is meant to make the csv file that I've saved on excel to pop up then I just select to bring it into the R environment. But when I type in the code and hit enter nothing happens. nothing pops up for me to choose anything.

I initially thought it was because I was using the unpaid version of excel so I got the Paid version, saved the csv file in there yet I cant see the file when I call the above function. Please what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `file.choose() Enter file name: ` that you enter. This assumes you're in the directory where the file was saved, you remember the name of the file... `getwd()` tells you which your 'home directory` is for your current session, that may be different from where you saved the file. `my_full_path <- list.files('~/some_dir/, pattern = '.csv', full.names = TRUE)` returns the full path to the saved .csv once you track it down, then `my_csv <- read.csv(my_full_path, headers = TRUE)` should read in your .csv. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: The response from `file.choose()` depends on how you are running R.  If you are running the command line version, you'll see a prompt in the console as @Chris said.  If you are running RStudio or R.app or Rgui you'll see a popup dialog.  If you are running it in some other way (e.g. through a web browser), it depends on what that system has set up.

Comment: Using RStudio on Windows I've had the problem of the file chooser appearing behind the RStudio window. Maybe that is worth considering: Does the file choos dialog appear somewhere hidden? Please state operating system and whether you work from the console or from within RStudio. Should you work from inside RStudio, try the file choose dialog that is included there by hitting Ctrl-O.

Comment: As @Bernhard pointed out, the file picker dialog (launched by `file.choose()`) can open underneath the active window; same can happen for the plot window. You can bring it up front quickly by cycling through the windows with `ALT` + `Tab`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions apparently it was an issue with the version of excel i saved the file with.